# How to disable eldoc doc minibuffer?

Tags: lsp-mode, echo-area, eldoc, eglot

While using eldoc, it constantly updates the minibuffer with the symbol on point. I like it, but would like the displayed lines to be lesser, as it covers a lot of my window.

I tried putting the following in my ~/.emacs file:

```
(setq
    lsp-signature-auto-activate t
    lsp-signature-doc-lines 1)

(setq eglot-ignored-server-capabilites '(:documentHighlightProvider))
```

from [here](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1315)
I tried a lot of other commands like :

```
(setq lsp-signature-auto-activate nil)
```

they did nothing.

I want to keep eldoc running. Just either stop using the minibuffer or use less of it.

Answer (score 4):

I solved using this:

```lisp
(setq eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(setq max-mini-window-height 3)
```

Solved using this.
It sets the max height the minibuffer can grow upto.